# Is there a real life application for the Bottleneck travelling salesman problem?

Tags: applications, traveling-salesman

The bottleneck TSP tries to find a Hamiltonian circle which minimizes the longest edge. Is there any real world application for this for example in transportation?

Answer (score 3):

The closest example that I could find in the literature is the following paper. The authors compared a special case of their problem when there are only two stations in the assembly line to a BTSP. I think it is a good place to start a deeper search in the applications.

*Delorme, Xavier, et al. "Minimizing the number of workers in a paced mixed-model assembly line." European Journal of Operational Research 272.1 (2019): 188-194.*